# How to call a subclass' method from the parent class implementation?

Tags: objective-c, oop

In Objective-C, say you have class `Parent`:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
@end

@implementation

+ (void)load {
  NSLog(@"class: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}

@end
```

and class `Child`:

```
@interface Child : Parent
@end
```

How can I make this so whenever `+[Child load]` gets called it logs the name of `Child` instead of the name of `Parent`? I'd prefer if I don't have to rewrite `+ (void)load` on each subclass of `Parent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` is an existing method (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/load).

lets say we have the following classes:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
+ (void)logClassName;
@end

@implementation Parent
+ (void)logClassName {
  NSLog(@"class: %@", NSStringFromClass(self));
}
@end

@interface Child : Parent
@end
```

now when i call the `logClassName` class method...

```
[Parent logClassName];
[Child logClassName];
```

i get the following output which is - if i got you right - exactly what you wanted:

**2015-11-11 22:56:19.029 OOP[676:11008] class: Parent

2015-11-11 22:56:19.030 OOP[676:11008] class: Child**

Comment: Even though irrelevant to my initial question, do you know if there's a way to implement a class method (such as load) that will be called by the class' subclasses?

Comment: I posted it as another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33661246/call-same-load-implementation-on-all-subclasses