# Call same +load implementation on all subclasses

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, given a parent class `Parent`:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
@end

@implementation
+ (void)load {
  NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
}
@end
```

and multiple other classes which subclass from `Parent` such as:

```
@interface Child1 : Parent
@end
```

Is it possible to have `+[Child# load]` call the same `+[Parent load]` without having to implement `load` for all subclasses of `Parent`?

Right now as it is, the program will only print `Hello, World!` once. The goal would be to have `Hello, World!` be printed `N + 1` times where `N` is the number of classes which inherit from `Parent`.

Comment: Try the `initialize` method instead of `load`.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `initialize` method, not the `load` method for this.

The `initialize` method will be called for each of your subclasses. If they don't explicitly implement the method, the base class' `initialize` method will be called which is what you want here.

Keep in mind that a reference to `self` in the parent class' `initialize` method will be a reference to the subclass.